# How to enable Safari scrolling over SVG's (object tags in scrolling div)?

Tags: javascript, css, object, svg, safari

I have the following code to display **a series of portfolio images** stored as SVG's in a **scrolling div**:

```
<div style="overflow:scroll;width:500px;height:500px">
  <object src=image1.svg></object>
  <object src=image2.svg></object>
  <object src=image3.svg></object>
</div>
```

Scrolling in Safari, **using two fingers or the mouse-wheel**, does not work **when the cursor is over one of the SVG's**.

The page behaves as expected (scrolling works everywhere) in Chrome and Firefox.

**Is there a Safari-specific CSS tag that enables scroll events to pass through the SVG's?**

The SVG's are drawn in object tags because they include some bitmapped elements that won't be displayed if they are called in img tags in webkit-based browsers.

**[temporary]** the page I am working on is [here](http://ozake.com/realisations).

Comment: try overflow: scroll; in css

Comment: It's already there, in the outside div, and when I tried a test case where the SVG's didn't fill up the space, I could scroll as long as the mouse was over some non-svg space.

Comment: So you do have scrollbars? The link you posted has a lot of content, hard to tell what you're talking about

Comment: I realize problem is only in Safari. I do have scrollbars on the outside "viewport" div. The problem is not that I can't scroll using the scrollbars, but that scrolling using the mouse wheel doesn't work when the mouse is over an object. I will clarify the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the height of the SVG files, which I presume you do, simply add total height to this:

```
<div id=content>
```

e.g. images are 300px high each, add style:

```
#content { height: 900px; }
```

And the outer should then scroll

If you don't know the height then measure them `onload` and add the height `#content` div on the fly as they load

Comment: I don't actually. They're all different and there's no easy way to get the information on the fly. But, I will try specifying a "more than enough" height to see what happens.

Comment: Changing the height of the #content div did not affect my ability to scroll the SVG's.

Comment: It looks good. It is late here... I'll try to find out why it behaves differently from my site tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: The reason it works is because the SVG's are not in object tags. I put a version of your code at dev.ozake.com/test.html. The first red dot is an object and the rest are not. Scrolling works normally over all but the first red dot.

Comment: Works perfectly for me on your dev page??

Comment: The main dev page (linked to in the question) now works because there is a transparent gif in front of the SVG's. The red-dot version doesn't work for me in Safari (dev.ozake.com/test.html). All the dots work but the first, which is in an object tag.

Answer (score 0):

The best answer I have come up with so far is to position a transparent image on top of the SVG's.

```
<img id=scroller src=spacer.gif
  width=500px height=10000px
  style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
```